Is Checking mounted Necessary for Quick Async Operations in Flutter?
I have an asynchronous function _getLocation, with multiple async method calls. Based on their results, I perform some actions using SetState.
I understand that it is not a mandatory to check for mounted, but I've heard it can prevent errors if the user navigates to another page while an async operation is still in progress. Do it really can happens(This issue hasn’t affected me in my experience with Flutter so far) and do I need to check mounted every time for async operations? Isn't it excessive? If it is, in which cases would it be beneficial to use it?
Future<void> _getLocation() async {
    try {
      Position position = await _determinePosition();
      if (!mounted) return;
      setState(() {
        coordinates = "${position.latitude} ${position.longitude}";
      });

      List<Placemark> placemarks =
          await placemarkFromCoordinates(position.latitude, position.longitude);

      if (!mounted) return;

      if (placemarks.isNotEmpty) {
        String city = placemarks[0].locality ?? 'City not found';
        setState(() {
          locationCity = city;
        });
        try {
          WeatherFactory wf =
              WeatherFactory("...");
          Weather weather = await wf.currentWeatherByCityName(city);

          if (!mounted) return;
          print("weather: ${weather}");
        } catch (weatherError) {
          if (!mounted) return;
          print("Weather fetch error: $weatherError");
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      if (!mounted) return;
      setState(() {
        coordinates = "";
        locationCity = "";
      });
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
          content: Text(
              'Geolocation is not available, please enable it in your App settings')));
    }
  }

method "_determinePosition" - classic one, that can return value with timeout
return await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
      locationSettings: locationSettings,
    ).timeout(const Duration(seconds: 5));


How can you be sure that an async operation is quick? If it's a network operation, the user might have a slow internet connection and the operation might take time. If the operation is gps one, the user might have low GPS signal and the operation might take time or never happen.
In your example, lets assume that the user is fetching the location. If the user is able to navigate away from the screen while the setState takes place then you will receive an error.
Same thing happens with other cases, for example while widgets are being animated, when passing a callback to a modal that contains the context ( for example, navigation callback) etc.
Always assume the worst scenario when taking decisions like this. Assume low internet connection, low gps signal, etc.
